# Topology of $\mathbb{R}/(x \sim nx)$

Tags: general-topology

Is anything known about the following set given the quotient topology?
$$
\mathbb{R} / (x \sim qx) \; \text{s.t.} 
$$
where $q \in \mathbb{Q} \backslash{0}$. What about 
$$
\mathbb{R} / (x \sim 2^n x)
$$
where here $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Note that the latter is the set of all pitch classes in music (we identify notes that are octaves apart)

EDIT: Changed $(x \sim nx)$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ to $(x \sim qx)$ for $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ in order to make the relation symmetric

Comment: What does $x \sim nx$ mean?

Comment: I'm quotienting by the equivalence relation of a given real number $x$ is to be identified with any integer multiple of it, $nx$

Comment: The first relation is not symmetric, and its symmetric closure is not transitive. So presumably the intention is to take the equivalence relation generated by that relation, which is how I wrote my answer.

Comment: @LeeMosher thanks for the catch - I've changed it above

Answer (score 5):

The equivalence relation generated by $x \sim nx$ ($x \in \mathbb R$, $n \in \mathbb Z \setminus 0$) has equivalence classes of the form $\{\frac{m}{n}x  \mid \frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb Q - \{0\}\}$. One of these equivalence classes is $\{0\}$, and every other equivalence class is dense in $\mathbb R$. It follows that the quotient space is a pretty terrible non-Hausdorff space: no two points in the quotient have disjoint neighborhoods. There's not much more to say.

For the equivalence relation $x \sim 2^n x$ ($x \in \mathbb R$, $n \in \mathbb Z$), the quotient of the positive $x$-axis is homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$, and the quotient of the negative $x$ axis is homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$; these two circles are disjoint in the quotient, and each of them is open in the quotient. So the image of $\mathbb R - \{0\}$ in the quotient space is an open subset homeomorphic to a disjoint union of two circles. Good so far, but now there is one more point to add: the origin $\{0\}$ forms a single equivalence class, and the only open subset of the quotient containing that point is the entire space.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. Is there a simple map from $\mathbb{R}^+ / (x \sim 2^n x)$ to $S^1$ to show that its homeomorphic? I'm not seeing it at the moment

Comment: Ah sorry, $[1,2]$ is a fundamental domain, and it behaves like $S^1 \cong \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ there.